# Naming a component of a vending machine

Tags: word-choice

I'm creating a computer program to simulate a snack vending machine. However, I'm having trouble with naming. I have *rows* and *columns* of different kinds of products. A singular snack is held in a *slot*. However, for any given row and column (e.g. B9) there are multiple slots containing many of the same product. What could I name this depth that contains multiple of the same product?

Comment: Vending machines are typically populated by ***coils***.

Comment: @IanMacDonald Coils of *Kit-Kat* ? Sounds  heavenly.

Comment: How about "count"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing you want a name for the position of the snack in a particular slot, so you can refer to it in your program?

If you have 50 chocolate bars in Slot B9 ready to vend, then each one of the bars occupies a 'cell' from 1 to 50 say. You  could use 'layer' or 'slice'.

Comment: What you're calling 'cell' is what I was calling 'slot'. However, I think I may want to adopt the word cell and use slot to indicate the entire space that holds the 50 chocolate bars in B9.

Answer (score 2):

Trays support a number of individual spaces. Each space has an auger that pushes outward the selected product. Technically you can refer to them as single auger spaces:

> - The trays can be adjusted up or down in one inch increments to provide additional headroom for vending taller products.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A quick poll of UK English speakers here reveals that most people call it a 'hole'!  But I think 'receptacle' might work well.